# Iterating through multiple levels of Child Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, iterator

I have this block of code. And I need to iterate through every child object, but child objects could have more children within them. The `Awake()` method is called when the program is first ran. So, I'm asking how to build an iterator that will check if there are children within the children. And then run `ResizeMeshCollection(MeshFilter[] collection)` on those children, until there are no more child objects.

```
    public class ResizeAsset : MonoBehaviour {


    void Awake()
    {
        ResizeMeshCollection(this.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>());
    }

    void ResizeMeshCollection(MeshFilter[] collection)
    {
        foreach (MeshFilter mf in collection)
        {
            mf.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            Transform tf = mf.GetComponent<Transform>();
            /// Resize logic here
            /// check if there are children under this child object, 
            /// Run ResizeMeshCollection() on
            /// all children until there are no more.
```

I'm sure that I do not want to run ResizeMeshCollection() within itself, nor do I  know if that is possible, but I just can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: The first sentance for the tag [tag:unity] is "DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)"

Comment: http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/recursion

Comment: So, is there anyway to do this? I understand calling the method within could have some undesired effects

Comment: When you call GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>() you get all meshfilter components on transform's children, even on children's childrens. So you will just need to call this once on the root transform

Comment: @luizcarlosfx Then I guess I need to work on my resize logic, because I am not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it is actually exactly how you want to do it. The method is called recursion. It is a very popular way of achieving what you are trying to do, nothing wrong with having a method calling itself, if done within certain guidelines like meeting certain criteria before executing itself again.